# Moving from SVN to Git while changing the repository structure

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, bitbucket

I'm in the process of migrating from SVN (cloudforge) to Git (bitbucket). I'd like to use git-svn to have a one-way synchronization of SVN to Git during a migration period - as described by [Atlassian's migration tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/migration#!migration-convert).

Our single SVN repo has been used to track multiple projects, where all projects have been on the same release schedule. The resulting structure of our SVN repository is unlike any examples I've been able to find:

```
/project_A  <- trunk
/project_B  <- trunk
/project_C  <- trunk
/branches/2013-12-20/project_A_2013-12-20
/branches/2013-12-20/project_B_2013-12-20
/branches/2013-12-20/project_C_2013-12-20
/branches/2014-03-19/project_A_2014-03-19
/branches/2014-03-19/project_B_2014-03-19
/branches/2014-03-19/project_C_2014-03-19
```

When we move to Git, I'd like each project to be in it's own Git repository, as each of the projects are quite large, and quite unrelated to each other (besides the identical branch/release schedule). I'd also like to adopt the [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow), which would give me a structure like:

project_A Repository:

```
/master
/develop
/release/2014-03-19
```

(and the same for the project_[B,C] Git repositories.

Is it possible to use *git svn clone* since I want the repository structure to change so drastically? If not, what is my best course of action to move to my new Git repositories while maintaining revision history?

Comment: When doing git svn clone, you can specify the path to a single project: `git svn clone svn://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/project_A`. Don't know about the branches though.

Comment: @user1615903, I've been thinking about this - and I supposed you are onto something. It's the branches that are really causing the complication.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two different ways

- Split repository before converting to Git

  - Create full dump of the whole repository (`svnadmin dump`)
  - Filter this dump for single-project layout with `svndumpfilter include --pattern ...` (SVN 1.7+)
  - Load dumps into separate repositories and convert without additional tricks (`-s` option of `git svn clone` will do all)
- Intead of dumb clone, use 'init'+'fetch' pair and **before fetch**, prepare by hand correct fetch-references specification inside `.git/config` in `[svn-remote]` section for needed branches: it can be wildcards, enumeration or just set of all branches (see samples on [Git-SVN page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_configuration))

Comment: Your suggestion of specifying references inside of .git/config got my wheels turning. I may be able to still use *git svn clone*, and specify multiple --branches options (I see that multiple branches can be specified). Will try.